# alternatives to rode nt4

Tags: rode

hi there,

would like to know your opinion how does the Audiotechnica AT8022 comes out in comparison to Rode NT4 when it comes to recording quality, susceptibility to handling noise, application scope, range. Audiotechnica is a bit less expensive as well as looks less bulky. Also looking at AT2022.

Any other alternatives for a stereo x-y in that price range?

thanks in advance for your replies

Answer (score 1):

I've not used the 8022, but the college I studied at had an 822 which could well be essentially the same microphone. I mostly used it for recording atmos and generally remember it a a mic which was easy to use with a good sound.

This sound was recorded with the 822:

[soundcloud]mark-durham/london-underground-train[/soundcloud]

http://soundcloud.com/mark-durham/london-underground-train

Handling noise was fine, but if you want to use it out and about I'd recommend getting a pistol grip and windjammer of some kind.

I've not used the NT4, but it looks more like a mic designed for the studio. It certainly has quite a wide body which may make it a more difficult to mount etc. Weight of NT4 is 480g, 8022 is 247g. There is also no protection for the capsules. This is all speculation though, perhaps some NT4 owners will chip in here?

Hope this helps,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I have captured some sweet ambiences with my 822.  I have not used any Rode products, but I do recommend the 822 for ambiences. (hopefully the 8022 isnt a step backwards).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've gotten some really nice recordings with NT4. I use it in the blimp mounted on a tripod, so the size or weight hasn't been a problem for me. I rarely walk around and record stereo handheld... Never used the AT, but i guess you'll get good but not mindblowing recordings with these microphones/pricerange.